# Bundle.main.urlでpathが取得できずnilが返ってくる

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

Xcodeのplaygroundでファイルのpathを取得しようとBundle.main.url()を使用しているのですがnilが返ってきてしまいます。ファイルはResourcesフォルダの中に置いています。
どうすればよいでしょうか？

```
import UIKit
import Vision
// 学習済みモデルを読み込む
// ビルド時にmlmodelをコンパイルしたmlmodelcが作られるのでそれをロードする
//TOLOv3Tiny.mlmodelのURLを取得//ここでnilが返ってくる
let modelURL: URL? = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "YOLOv3Tiny", withExtension: "mlmodel")

guard let model = try?VNCoreMLModel(for: MLModel(contentsOf: modelURL!))else{
    fatalError()
}
```

[image: ファイル]

Comment: ご自分で「ビルド時にmlmodelをコンパイルしたmlmodelcが作られる」と書いているのに、`withExtension: "mlmodel"`としておられますね。`withExtension: "mlmodelc"`では試して見られましたか?

Comment: mlmodelcを使用するとnilではなく、きちんとurlを取得できました。ありがとうございました！